# Problems with double queries

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to execute 2 query in one button click.. It doesn't seem to work and just closes automatically. Can anyone help me or explain to me why my code doesn't work? Here's the code:

```
test = 1;
{
    connection.Open();
    string strTemp = " [StudentNum] Text, [StudentName] Text, [Section] Text, [TimeIn] Text, [TimeOut] Text, [Status] Text";
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    myCommand.Connection = connection;
    myCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [" + date + "](" + strTemp + ")";
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (test == 1)
    {
        OleDbCommand commandl = new OleDbCommand();
        commandl.Connection = connection;
        commandl.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ['" + date + "']([StudentNum],[StudentName],[Section]) select [StudentNo],[Name],[Section] from StudInfo";
        commandl.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful description; you should include any runtime error (or, hopefully, a caught exception). See [ask] and [tour].

Comment: There is nothing in your code that has anything to do with "closes automatically". You need to provide a [mcve] for us to see what is going on.

Comment: My guess would be that your DBMS doesn't like a table named `2019-03-04` or `04/03/2019` or whatever else you might have in `date`and that somewhere in the code you haven't posted you have a `catch` with an empty code block to handle it, but it's hard to say. I'd suggest you find a good Access tutorial.

Comment: Don't use apostrophes when defining a table name, just `[ ]`. Access does not have problem with table named with either of those date formats. Why would you create a table for a specific date?

Comment: @June7 Thanks for the answer.. That's just what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the apostrophes delimiting table name.

`commandl.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [" + date + "]([StudentNum],[StudentName],[Section]) select [StudentNo],[Name],[Section] from StudInfo";`